# Jquery on loading html page with sending data along the path

Tags: jquery

can anyone please tell me how can i retrieve data in jquery when i send data using load function along with destination url. so how to retrieve the data variable in person.html...

code:

```
data="name";
$("div").load("person.html",data);
```

and another one is can anyone tell me how to change the icon  on the listname when i click it suppose  i have `->ITEMS 1)item1 2)item2 3)item3`

suppose if i click on ITEMS  the arrow(->)  should change like (<-) this and ITEMS should Dissapper..

is there any plug in available for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the data you need to have a page that can retrieve data from the request. For example if it was a php file:

JS:

```
$('div').load('person.php', {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'});
```

PHP:

```
Your name is: <?php echo $_GET['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $_GET['last_name']; ?>
```